# Extract and delete all .gz in a directory- Linux

Tags: linux, gzip, extract, gunzip

I have a directory. It has about 500K .gz files.

How can I extract all .gz in that directory and delete the .gz files?

Comment: A `.gz` file need not necessarily be an archive.  In that case you wouldn't have anything to delete upon performing `gzip -d file.gz`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 177):

This should do it:

```
gunzip *.gz
```

Comment: ... unless that gives you an 'argmuent too big' error.  In which case, you'll want to use something like `find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -name '*.gz' -print0 | xjobs -0 -l50 -v2  gunzip` to restrict instances to 50 arguments each (and to run them in parallel).

Comment: ... or just `find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -name '*.gz' -exec gunzip {} +` to run them sequentially. Remove the `-maxdepth 1` to also traverse subdirectories, and replace `"$dir"` with the directory you want to examine (just `.` for current directory, or on Linux simply omit the directory).

Answer (score 25):

@techedemic is correct but is missing '.' to mention the current directory, and this command go throught all subdirectories.

```
find . -name '*.gz' -exec gunzip '{}' \;
```

Answer (score 21):

There's more than one way to do this obviously.

```
    # This will find files recursively (you can limit it by using some 'find' parameters. 
    # see the man pages
    # Final backslash required for exec example to work
    find . -name '*.gz' -exec gunzip '{}' \;

    # This will do it only in the current directory
    for a in *.gz; do gunzip $a; done
```

I'm sure there's other ways as well, but this is probably the simplest.

And to remove it, just do a `rm -rf *.gz` in the applicable directory

Answer (score 4):

Extract all gz files in current directory and its subdirectories:

```
 find . -name "*.gz" | xargs gunzip
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to extract a single file use:

gunzip file.gz

It will extract the file and remove .gz file.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
for foo in *.gz
do
  tar xf "$foo"
  rm "$foo"
done
```

Comment: Nothing in the question suggests that these are `tar` files.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ls -1 | grep -E "\.tar\.gz$" | xargs -n 1 tar xvfz
```

Then Try:

```
ls -1 | grep -E "\.tar\.gz$" | xargs -n 1 rm
```

This will untar all .tar.gz files in the current directory and then delete all the .tar.gz files. If you want an explanation, the "|" takes the stdout of the command before it, and uses that as the stdin of the command after it. Use "man *command*" w/o the quotes to figure out what those commands and arguments do. Or, you can research online.

Answer (score -1):

for deleting all .gz files in each and every directory. Please use this commands

step:1

> cd /

step :2

> find . -type f -iname *.gz -delete